# Downloading dlib on Raspberry Pi, pip keeps outputting error when I try?

Tags: python, dlib

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-dhth2xud/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record /tmp/pip-7p82qhms-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dhth2xud/dlib/
```

This is the error I keep getting, when simply running `sudo pip3 install dlib`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error. Turns out you need to install those prerequisits on the Raspberry Pi:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

I read that it helps to free up RAM by disabling GUI start (`sudo raspi-config` and under Boot options change from GUI to Console) but that alone didn't help.
I then followed the Ubuntu installation instructions [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/) (the 3 commands above) and then `sudo pip3 install dlib` stopped showing this error and started installation.